# What is the best way to keep Apache DBCP connection pool for a Java scheduler task

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbcp

I have to develop Java scheduler task (Job) which has to run each and every 5 minutes periodically.
I have two ideas two keep the connection pool and i don't know what should be the best way.

Method 1 :
Crates connection pool each and every 5 minutes 
Query
Closes the connection

Method 2 :
Crates connection pool at initiation of the Java Job
Query each and every 5 minutes
Keeps the connection alive without closing

I just wanted to know what should be the ideal way to handle this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of a connection pool is to provide you with connections on demand. So don't recreate the pool every time. Create the pool once, keep it alive, and get a connection for each job. Close it when the job is done so it is made available to the pool again. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thank you , using the way you mentioned